# SIGPIPE in C++ determining which TCP socket is disconnected

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm using Linux/Ubuntu. I've written a pair of classes that implement a TCP server and TCP client, respectively. Part of the code is to have graceful recovery from disconnects. My only problem is with SIGPIPE. I've written code to capture the signal, but I'd like it to start the "attempt to reconnect" process on the class instance that hit the broken pipe. signal( SIGPIPE, functionname ) requires function name to be C-type function or static class method.

How can I determine which socket the SIGPIPE occurred for if I've got multiple instances of my classes in an application?

Comment: Post what code you have.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGPIPE` is useless for TCP. This signal was invented for shell pipes (e.g. `proc_1 | proc_2 | proc_3`), because `SIGINT` is only delivered to the last process in the shell pipe. When the last process is killed and the previous process tries to write into its `stdout` it gets killed with `SIGPIPE` because the reader of the pipe terminated and so on, effectively killing all processes involved in the shell pipe. And this is why the signal has word *pipe* in its name.

---

Normally people ignore `SIGPIPE` completely when doing TCP:

```
// Early in main().
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

And/or:

```
ssize_t rc = send(..., MSG_NOSIGNAL);
if(rc == -1)
    // errno can be EPIPE
```

This way your just deal with error from `send` and `errno` is set to `EPIPE`.

When `SIGPIPE` is ignored it is not necessary to use `MSG_NOSIGNAL`, but it is still good practice, IMO.